# Change tooltips color d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add tooltips on a donut chart using `src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"`
I want the font color of tooltips change when user switches to different pieces of the donut.

For example, when user hovers over the orange part, the font color is orange.When user hovers over the blue part, the font color of tooltip change to blue accordingly.

I was trying to do this by adding if-else statements after d3.tip(), but it doesn't work. I also create a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Ghs4rovDHIdtQkgNS8y?p=preview).

I know there are many ways to add tooltips, but in this example I want to stick to use `this "http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"`

Appreciate if anyone can help with this!

```
 var tip = d3.
    tip().
    attr('class', 'd3-tip').
    offset([100, 0]).
    html(function(d) {
      if (d.fruit == 'Apple') {
        return "<strong style = 'color:red'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.count + '</span>';
      } else if (d.fruit == 'Banana') {
        return "<strong style = 'color:blue'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:blue'>" + d.count + '</span>';
      } else {
        return "<strong style = 'color:orange'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:orange'>" + d.count + '</span>';
      }
    });
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to control the colors with classes? so in the css you'd have strong.apple, strong.apple + span { color: red; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access the `data` property on the `d` parameter to get the `fruit` and `count`. Like this:

```
if (d.data.fruit == 'Apple') {
    return "<strong style = 'color:blue'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:blue'>" + d.data.count + '</span>';
} else if (d.data.fruit == 'Banana') {
    return "<strong style = 'color:red'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.data.count + '</span>';
} else {
    return "<strong style = 'color:orange'>Count: </strong> <span style='color:orange'>" + d.data.count + '</span>';
}
```

Also looks like you had your `Apple` and `Banana` colors backwards so I fixed that above too.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking "d" indicates "data". Can you explain what does "d" mean here? And why the count number is undifined here?

Comment: I updated answer for count too. As for what `d` indicates there is more in the `d` object other than `data`. Looks like graph values and angles relevant to that pie slice.

Comment: @newb I believe in general `d` is chart display data and the data property in `d` is chart graph data perhaps.